# What books teach the formula for the # of k-permutations of n objects, with x types, and $r_1,⋯,r_x$ = the number of each type of object?

Tags: reference-books, combinatorics

Some of ***my 16 year old students*** hanker after the formula  for the # of k-permutations of n objects, with x types, where $r_1, ⋯, r_x$ = the number of each type of object. This is more generalized [than this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7765/19348).

What books accessibly teach this formula? What books gently expound — fill in all gaps and steps in —  [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/37218) by Prof. [Suresh Venkatasubramanian](https://mathoverflow.net/users/972/suresh-venkat)?

The book doesn't have to be written for 16 year olds. You can recommend books for undergraduates, but they must be readable and  easygoing.

Comment: Rather than a **textbook**, which at the high school level would be much broader in scope (covering many topics that would be taught throughout the high school year the book is used for) and thus would probably only cover something this specialized rather tangentially if at all, I recommend something intended as supplementary reading for better students, such as **Mathematics of Choice. How to Count Without Counting** by Ivan Niven (1965; [.pdf file](https://mathsmartinthomas.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/niven-maths-of-choice.pdf)).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro thanks! I edited my answer. I didn't mean to limit question to textbooks for high school.

Comment: Best derivation I've come around is ["The Tao of BOOKKEEPER"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/recitations/MIT6_042JF10_rec15_sol.pdf).

Comment: I think Hart College Algebra, chapter on permutations and combinations, has right coverage and easiness. I'm on my phone so can't cut and paste, but archive.org has a pdf of the 1926 edition.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro,vonbrand The question indicates (check the links, especially the mathoverflow one) that $k$ is allowed to be less than $\sum r_i$. I was not able to find a discussion of this much harder version of the problem in Niven, Tao of BOOKKEEPER, or Hart. If it's in one of those and I missed it, it might be helpful to provide page references.

Comment: Of the combinatorics books on my shelf, the only one in which I was able to locate a discussion of this problem was Riordan's *Combinatorial Analysis*, page 13. Unfortunately, RIordan's discussion is even briefer than Venkatasubramanian's. If you're going to find it, the most likely place is in a book with a detailed discussion of exponential generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another recommendation ist Vilenkin: Conbinatorics, see https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Combinatorics%20Vilenkin%20N.Ia.%20(1971).pdf

A good book for undergraduates is

L. Lovász, J. Pelikán, K. Vesztergombi:Discrete Mathematics, elementary and beyond. Springer, 2003, ISBN: 978-0-387-95585-8, https://doi.org/10.1007/b97469

Answer (score 0):

The [lecture notes](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Exinweiyu/421.Q1.17w/) from Xinwei Yu's Finite Mathematics course at the University of Alberta contain a discussion that may be at the right level. See [Generating Functions II](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/%7Exinweiyu/421.Q1.17w/421Q1Winter2017_L15_20170213.pdf), Example 5. This example is slightly more general than your problem, but describes the necessary techniques in detail. Exercise 2 is exactly your problem.